# Is there a way to throw typeError without curly brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my try-catch block every thing works fine, but when I try to make my catch statement one line by removing curly brackets, it returns an error

```
//problem
.catch(error => throw new TypeError(error))


//no problem
.catch(error => {
    throw new TypeError(error))
}
```

Comment: `throw` is a statement, not an expression, and you can only use a single *expression* in the bracket-less arrow function syntax.

Comment: the link you added, doesn't relate to the question

Comment: The answer does though.